# I can't select the same component in different stages of the flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have a problem with webdriverIO v7, i'm trying to select the same component in different stages of the flow. The first time i can click on the button, but the second time i can't, have you any idea about this issue I'm using an application developed in React

[image: First click]

[image: Second click]

This is the spec

```
await DiscoverPage.clickOnTakeALook();
await PropertyDetailsPage.switchToTab();
await PropertyDetailsPage.clickOnBtnReservePropertyDetails();
await CheckoutPage.selectTypeOfStay();
await CheckoutPage.selectGuest();
await CheckoutPage.clickOnBtnContinue();
await CheckoutPage.setValueInStayRequeriments();
await CheckoutPage.clickOnBtnContinue();
const textPaymentMethods = await 
CheckoutPage.getTextPaymentsMethods();
expect(textPaymentMethods).toEqual('Payment Methods');
});
```

This is the button and the function where i use it

```
get btnContinue() {
return $('[data-testid="btnContinue"]');
}

async clickOnBtnContinue() {
await this.btnContinue.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 30000 });
await this.btnContinue.waitForClickable({ timeout: 30000 });
await this.btnContinue.click();
}
```

Comment: Some part of code can help for find, lot of things can happen

Comment: hey @LutherW I added the code

Comment: this.btnContinue.click is promise ?

Comment: Yes, is strange because the first click is okay, and when I try to use it in the second stage, I can't, I know that it show the same component always in 4 stages, so I don't know if webdriver becomes crazy in the second button "Continue"

Comment: what do you do onClick ? (code sample please)

Comment: This is the button component

`const ButtonContainer = (
    <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        data-testid="btnContinue"
        disabled={buttonDisabled}
        form={formIDForButton}
        onClick={buttonCallback}
        type={type}
        variant="contained"
      >
        {buttonText}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );`

@LutherW